# Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?

Tags: rust

What follows is just used as an example, and not valid Rust code.

```
struct Vec<T: Sized, Count> {
    a: [T; Count]
}
```

Something like it is possible in C++ templates, but I haven't seen it in Rust.

Comment: I don't think so, but [it has been discussed before](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1z3dnx/ints_in_generic_type_parameters/)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## Rust 1.51

Use *const generics*:

```
struct Vec<T: Sized, const COUNT: usize> {
    a: [T; COUNT],
}
```

## Previous versions

[RFC 2000 — const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) introduces support for this and progress is tracked in [issue #44580](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580).

If you look at the design of Rust, you will notice that it started first by tackling the hardest problems (memory-safe, data-race free) but there are otherwise lots of areas where it is "incomplete" (compared to what could be achieved).

In particular, generic structures and functions started out somewhat limited:

- lack of Higher Kinded Types (HKT)
- lack of non-type parameters => arrays are special-cased, and implementing a trait for an array is [a known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/7622), the work-around being to implement it for a few different dimensions
- lack of variadic parameters => tuples are special-cased, and implementing a trait for all tuples is similarly difficult

For the moment, not all of these are implemented, not because they are not desired but simply because time was lacking. The idea of Rust 1.0 was not to release a final product that would not evolve, but a stable base from which to start; some or maybe all will come.

Comment: @Byron: For information, non-type parameters are coming with the [Pi Types Trilogy](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1930), still at RFC stage though.

Comment: In 2020 it seems we still cannot use it? Thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n: Not quite yet, indeed. There is a proposal to stabilize a [minimum subset of const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74878) which would allow it, and hope that it will be implemented around the end of the year.

Comment: Report from THE FUTURE (2023): I just used this on Rust stable (1.65.0) and it worked as written.

Comment: Why does not the compiler allow `COUNT` to be `u32` and only `usize`?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco: Array sizes are `usize`, slice sizes are `usize`, collection sizes in general are `usize`. Not really a compiler choice, more of a library one.

Answer (score 9):

While waiting for Rust to gain first-class support for this, there are crates that provide certain levels of this functionality, such as:

- [typenum](https://crates.io/crates/typenum)
- [generic-array](https://crates.io/crates/generic-array)