# Is there a good way to convert a Vec<T> to an array?

Tags: rust

Is there a good way to convert a `Vec<T>` with size `S` to an array of type `[T; S]`? Specifically, I'm using a function that returns a 128-bit hash as a `Vec<u8>`, which will always have length 16, and I would like to deal with the hash as a `[u8, 16]`.

Is there something built-in akin to the `as_slice` method which gives me what I want, or should I write my own function which allocates a fixed-size array, iterates through the vector copying each element, and returns the array?

Comment: it's one line. use itertools:Itertools; my_array.iter_mut().set_from(my_vector.iter().cloned());

Comment: @donbright doesn t this result in a memory allocation?

Comment: i am sorry im not 100% sure what you mean.... you can view the generated assembler here (click the ... by Run and hit ASM): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=088605093493b42833e08b8698841f20

Comment: looking back at this now, the user, depending on intended platform, may be able to use a unsafe transmute, which would in theory eliminate copying ("memory allocation"?) .. and allow to use the bytes as-is

Comment: `as_chunks` method does the trick. Experimental at the moment writing this.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Arrays must be completely initialized, so you quickly run into concerns about what to do when you convert a vector with too many or too few elements into an array. These examples simply panic.

As of [Rust 1.51](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.51.0/RELEASES.md#version-1510-2021-03-25) you can parameterize over an array's length.

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn demo<T, const N: usize>(v: Vec<T>) -> [T; N] {
    v.try_into()
        .unwrap_or_else(|v: Vec<T>| panic!("Expected a Vec of length {} but it was {}", N, v.len()))
}
```

As of [Rust 1.48](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1480-2020-11-19), each size needs to be a specialized implementation:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn demo<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> [T; 4] {
    v.try_into()
        .unwrap_or_else(|v: Vec<T>| panic!("Expected a Vec of length {} but it was {}", 4, v.len()))
}
```

As of Rust 1.43:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn demo<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> [T; 4] {
    let boxed_slice = v.into_boxed_slice();
    let boxed_array: Box<[T; 4]> = match boxed_slice.try_into() {
        Ok(ba) => ba,
        Err(o) => panic!("Expected a Vec of length {} but it was {}", 4, o.len()),
    };
    *boxed_array
}
```

See also:

- [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25428920/155423)
- [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423)
- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)

Comment: For me, this fails with `the trait \`std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<[T]>>\` is not implemented for \`std::boxed::Box<[T; 3]>\``.
Is this new?
(The vector I supply is size 3, and I've changed the "demo" function accordingly).

Comment: @Alien_AV [works for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=779b1789e20d5fda0ac16f0db669fded).