# How to concatenate arrays of known lengths?

Tags: arrays, rust, concatenation

I have two arrays of known lengths:

```
let left: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
let right: [u8; 3] = [3, 4, 5];
```

My first attempt:

```
let whole: [u8; 5] = left + right;
```

fails with the error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot add `[u8; 2]` to `[u8; 3]`
  --> /home/fadedbee/test.rs:25:29
   |
25 |         let whole: [u8; 5] = left + right;
   |                              ---- ^ ----- [u8; 3]
   |                              |
   |                              [u8; 2]
```

Likewise:

```
let whole: [u8; 5] = left.concat(right);
```

fails with:

```
error[E0599]: the method `concat` exists for array `[u8; 2]`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> /home/fadedbee/test.rs:25:29
   |
25 |         let whole: [u8; 5] = left.concat(right);
   |                                   ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `[u8; 2]` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<[u8] as std::slice::Concat<_>>::Output = _`
```

I'm currently using an expression of the form:

```
let whole: [u8; 5] = [left[0], left[1], right[0], right[1], right[2]];
```

but this is dozens of elements for my actual use-case and is prone to typos.

@Emoun kindly pointed out that I'd misused `concat`.

Trying it properly:

```
 let whole: [u8; 5] = [left, right].concat();
```

I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> /home/fadedbee/test.rs:32:31
   |
32 |         let whole: [u8; 5] = [left, right].concat();
   |                                     ^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 2 elements, found one with 3 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `[u8; 2]`
             found array `[u8; 3]`
```

How do I concatenate arrays of known lengths into a fixed length array?

Comment: Similar previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757355/how-do-i-collect-into-an-array (Not voting to close as dup because that question is more general, and it makes sense to be able to concatenate two arrays in a manner different than collecting an arbitrary iterator into an array.)

Comment: I see someone is preparing the answer for you here  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84a67bd519c327e28a6a23b16518926b

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess there is a better answer, but you can do like this:

```
fn main() {
    let left: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
    let right: [u8; 3] = [3, 4, 5];

    let whole: [u8; 5] = {
        let mut whole: [u8; 5] = [0; 5];
        let (one, two) = whole.split_at_mut(left.len());
        one.copy_from_slice(&left);
        two.copy_from_slice(&right);
        whole
    };

    println!("{:?}", whole);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's less bad than the long-hand way that I'm currently doing this: `let whole: [u8; 5] = [left[0], left[1], right[0], right[1], right[2]];`, but with dozens of elements.

Comment: The problem is that the `whole` array is initialized two times, first time by filling it with zeroes, second time by doing the real stuff. It may be solved by using [MaybeUninit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @yolenoyer: Like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5097cb9e93238165e685d67a81210d12).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks! Why don't you propose it as an answer? It looks to be a better solution

Comment: @yolenoyer: Generally speaking, I think `unsafe` code should be avoided unless absolutely necessary—especially by those who are new to Rust.  I put it as a comment for completeness, not as a suggestion for use.  I think your approach is the right one in most circumstances.  Hopefully, when `const generics` is stabilised, there will be library methods for doing this.

Comment: @eggyal Ok, got it. If interested, my first successful try with `MaybeUninit` is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b6bac668430ac4cef828e7ba3695b7f), trying to keep the `split_at_mut()` method. It's a bit more verbose than your version, and I'm not sure if it's better than my original answer...

Comment: Once `const_evaluatable_checked` lands, we can give this a proper function signature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041830/how-to-concatenate-arrays-of-known-lengths/67085709#67085709

Answer (score 7):

If you want to avoid the overhead of initializing the target array, you can use `MaybeUninit()` and unsafe code:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [4, 5];
let concatenated: [u8; 5] = unsafe {
    let mut result = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
    let dest = result.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8;
    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(a.as_ptr(), dest, a.len());
    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(b.as_ptr(), dest.add(a.len()), b.len());
    result.assume_init()
};
```

Once Rust fully supports const generics, it will be possible to put this code in a function. On Nightly, this is already possible today using the `generic_const_expr` feature:

```
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub fn concat_arrays<T, const M: usize, const N: usize>(a: [T; M], b: [T; N]) -> [T; M + N] {
    let mut result = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
    let dest = result.as_mut_ptr() as *mut T;
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(a.as_ptr(), dest, M);
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(b.as_ptr(), dest.add(M), N);
        std::mem::forget(a);
        std::mem::forget(b);
        result.assume_init()
    }
}
```

Note that we don't need to make any assumptions about `T`, since all Rust types can be moved by bitwise copy.

Comment: Could you explain why we need forget here?

Comment: @koral We copied the data into a new array using bitwise copies, but the drop checker in the compiler is not aware that we did, so the destructors for each item would be called if we didn't `forget()` the old arrays. This is not an issue in the example above, since integers don't have destructors. We would not need this if we'd assume `T: Copy`, but if we don't make that assumption, we can't make copies of the data without telling the compiler not to drop the data in the source.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of the [`concat()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) method is not quite right. Here is how you do it:

```rust
fn main(){
    let left: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
    let right: [u8; 2] = [3, 4];
    
    assert_eq!([left, right].concat(), [1,2,3,4]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that only works for arrays of identical lengths.  (I'd previously updated the question.)  I get: `expected an array with a fixed size of 2 elements, found one with 3 elements`.  I'll add this error, in full, to the question.

Comment: This results in a `Vec<u8>`, not in a `[u8; 4]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:
Basically you will get the vec first, then try to convert it to an array.

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

pub fn array_concat() {
    let left: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
    let right: [u8; 3] = [3, 4, 5];
    let whole: Vec<u8> = left.iter().copied().chain(right.iter().copied()).collect();

    let _whole: [u8; 5] = whole.try_into().unwrap();
}
```

Note: `try_into` will works with 1.48
([Is there a good way to convert a Vec<T> to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570607/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-a-vect-to-an-array))

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to use `copied()` then you can try below snippet:

```rust
pub fn array_concat3() {
    let a1 = [1, 2, 3];
    let a2 = [4, 5, 6, 7];

    let mut whole: Vec<u8> = a1.iter().chain(a2.iter()).map(|v| *v).collect();
    let whole: [u8; 7] = whole.try_into().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", whole);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @yolenoyer's answer, this works, but requires `cargo +nightly test` at the moment to enable `const_evaluatable_checked`.

```
#![feature(const_generics)]
#![feature(const_evaluatable_checked)]

pub fn concat<T: Copy + Default, const A: usize, const B: usize>(a: &[T; A], b: &[T; B]) -> [T; A+B] {
    let mut whole: [T; A+B] = [Default::default(); A+B];
    let (one, two) = whole.split_at_mut(A);
    one.copy_from_slice(a);
    two.copy_from_slice(b);
    whole
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::concat;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let a: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
        let b: [u8; 3] = [3, 4, 5];

        let c: [u8; 5] = concat(&a, &b);

        assert_eq!(c, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to [Sven Marnach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72461302/8073702), if you don't mind using nightly features (even unfinished ones), you can do like this:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![feature(inline_const)]
#![feature(maybe_uninit_array_assume_init)]

use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

fn concat_arrays<T, const M: usize, const N: usize>(a: [T; M], b: [T; N]) -> [T; M + N] {
    let mut result = [const { MaybeUninit::uninit() }; M + N];
    let dest = result.as_mut_ptr() as *mut T;
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(a.as_ptr(), dest, M);
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(b.as_ptr(), dest.add(M), N);
        std::mem::forget(a);
        std::mem::forget(b);
        MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(result)
    }
}
```

Note that calling `std::mem::forget` here is safe because the memory corresponding to `a` and `b` has already been moved into `result` and is no longer being used, so there is no need for additional **destruction** and **cleanup** of them when the function exits (when their scope ends). This trick can be performed when pursuing ultimate performance, but `std::mem::forget` should generally be used with caution since it can also be used to transfer memory ownership (compared to [std::mem::ManuallyDrop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html#relationship-with-manuallydrop)).

Answer (score 0):

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    let left: [u8; 2] = [1, 2];
    let right: [u8; 3] = [3, 4, 5];

    let vector_a: Vec<u8> = left.into_iter().chain(right).collect();
    println!("vector_a: {vector_a:?}");

    let vector_b: Vec<u8> = [&left[..], &right[..]].concat();
    println!("vector_b: {vector_b:?}");

    assert_eq!(vector_a, vector_b);

    let array: [u8; 5] = vector_a.try_into().unwrap();
    println!("array: {array:?}");
}
```

The output ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=756d8ad2e2af27c14f9c8612d04ac185)):

```
vector_a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vector_b: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to turn arrays into vectors (requiring heap allocation and copying) before creating another vector and finally creating the required array back on the stack?  Does rustc optimise all of these vectors away at compile time?

Comment: @fadedbee It may, [but it actually doesn't](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ca3nqqeYT). Anyway, it is better to play safe and use `copy_from_slice()` as in the accepted answer.