# Initialize slice of an uninitialized array

Tags: arrays, rust, initialization, slice

I have an odd case where I want to initialize some segments of an array as copies of an existing array, and call a function to initialize the other elements. Naively, I'd like to do something like this:

```rust
fn build_array(input: [char; 8]) -> [char; 25] {
    let mut out: [char; 25];
    out[6..10].copy_from_slice(input[0..4]);
    out[16..20].copy_from_slice(input[4..8]);

    for i in 0..25 {
        if (6..10).contains(i) || (16..20).contains(i) {
            continue;
        }
        out[i] = some_func();
    }
}
```

Obviously I could just initialize the array, but that would be inefficient. I was surprised to find that wrapping the `copy_from_slice()` calls in an unsafe block does not make this compile. Creating multiple array segments and concatenating them doesn't seem to simplify things based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041830/how-to-concatenate-arrays-of-known-lengths).

Does anyone know of an idiomatic and efficient way to accomplish what I want to do here?

Edit: `some_func()` here is meant as a placeholder, the elements that aren't provided in `input` don't all have the same value.

Comment: I don't see how any of this is preferable than initializing the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not worry about the cost of initializing the elements. Especially when the optimizer may eliminate it.

If you really need that, e.g. for a very big array, the Rust way is to use [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html):

```rust
use std::mem::{self, MaybeUninit};
use std::ptr;

fn build_array(input: [char; 8]) -> [char; 25] {
    // SAFETY: `MaybeUninit` is always considered initialized (replace with
    // `MaybeUninit::uninit_array()` once stabilized).
    let mut out: [MaybeUninit<char>; 25] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };
    // SAFETY: source and destination derived from references, slices are of
    // the correct length (replace with `MaybeUninit::write_slice()` once stabilized).
    unsafe {
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            input[0..4].as_ptr(),
            out[6..10].as_mut_ptr().cast::<char>(),
            4,
        );
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            input[4..8].as_ptr(),
            out[16..20].as_mut_ptr().cast::<char>(),
            4,
        );
    }

    for i in 0..25 {
        if (6..10).contains(&i) || (16..20).contains(&i) {
            continue;
        }
        out[i].write(some_func());
    }

    // SAFETY: `MaybeUninit<T>` has the same layout as `T`, initialized above
    // (replace with `MaybeUninit::array_assume_init()` once stabilized).
    unsafe { mem::transmute(out) }
}
```

Like you can see, this involves non-trivial unsafe code, so I highly recommend to not do that unless really necessary and you know well what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for showing how this would be done! I will follow your advice and not try to optimize out the element initialization unless I really need to.