# What is the most efficient method for converting known length vector to array in Rust?

Tags: performance, rust, memory, type-conversion

> Because I am developing an MLops framework that supports multiple types of database as backend and allows users to customize some fields. As the number of these fields is unknown at compiling time, I can only represent them using a vec. However, a trait method for one of the databases needs to be called frequently when inserting data, and its signature only supports using an array type. The solution provided for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29570662/8073702) offers a good approach, but I believe it still involves memory allocation on the heap, which may not be fast enough for frequent data insertion in such a scenario and could slow down the users' entire application .

Suppose there's a vector of certain type with known size:

```rust
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
```

How can we turn it into an array?

The method is expected to have minimal memory overhead, without any unnecessary clone operations or operations on the heap, etc.

I've tried this solution:

```rust
fn vec_to_array(vec: Vec<i32>) -> [i32; 4] {
    let boxed_slice = vec.into_boxed_slice();
    let ptr = Box::into_raw(boxed_slice) as *mut i32;
    unsafe { std::ptr::read(ptr); }
}
```

However, it appears to have poor performance since it requires memory allocation on the heap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good way to convert a Vec<T> to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29570662/20665825)

Comment: I'm not sure. But what about the memory overhead with `try_into()`?

Comment: Do you have a measurable performance problem or are you just stressing about something that might not happen? Be wary of premature optimization! Normally Rust is pretty good about not using resources it doesn't need, but if you're converting large vectors into large arrays on an extremely frequent basis you may need to address this at the *algorithmic* level rather than through micro-optimizations.

Comment: `try_into()` does involve copying similar to your handwritten solution (see source code [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#3229)). There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080940/20665825) that shows how to convert `&[i32]` to `&[i32; 4]`, which does not involve copying.

Comment: @tadman You're right. But it could be an operation that occurs with (possibly) high frequency within our database application. Maybe I should just go ahead now.

Comment: @JonasFassbender What about the method in `arrayvec` crate? I've found that this maybe work:

`let mut array_vec = ArrayVec::<[i32; 4]>::new();
array_vec.extend_from_slice(&vec[..]);
let array = array_vec.into_inner().unwrap();`

Comment: `ArrayVec::into_inner` also uses `ptr::read` and therefore copies its contents to a new array (see [here](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.7.2/src/arrayvec/arrayvec.rs.html#664)).

Comment: If it's a frequent operation, then the real question is why bother with an array in the first place? You already have a `Vec`. Why not stick with it? Converting requires moving data, which is pointless if you can avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good way to convert a Vec<T> to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570607/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-a-vect-to-an-array)

Comment: @tadman I'm working with a MLops framework supporting multiple database as backend, and one of which needs array here in its trait method. Since I wanna users can customize fields, the concrete number of these fiels is unknown as compile time. So it represents as Vec<F> in my crate but needs to be converted to array when used with certain backend.

Comment: @Zephyr Not yet. I've edited my question to explain the difference.

Comment: Do you need a literal array, or just an array reference like `&[X]`? If it's just a reference, a `Vec<X>` can provide that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is probably slow because it's leaking memory. The box you create is never freed. In order to write this correctly, you need to free the box without freeing the items in the slice (they have been copied naively), which you can do with [`ManuallyDrop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html).

```rs
let boxed_slice = vec.into_boxed_slice();
let ptr = Box::into_raw(boxed_slice);
let arr = unsafe { (ptr as *mut [T; 4]).read() };

unsafe { drop(Box::from_raw(ptr as *mut [ManuallyDrop<T>; 4])) };

arr
```

This doesn't require an allocation. It allocates when the capacity of the `Vec` is different from the length. Also, this function (just like yours) must be marked unsafe.

However, it's almost certainly equal to or faster than your method to just use `try_into`.

```rs
vec.try_into().unwrap()
```

This doesn't allocate.

There's also some other ways to create an array. If the `Vec` is exactly the right size, which usually happens if it was just created from a literal, then you can turn it into a boxed array with the same method, without allocating.

```rs
fn boxed_array<const LEN: usize>(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Box<[i32; LEN]> {
    vec.try_into().unwrap()
}
```

If you don't need ownership, then you can once again avoid allocating.

```rs
fn slice_to_array<const LEN: usize>(slice: &[i32]) -> &[i32; LEN] {
    slice.try_into().unwrap()
}
```

But keep in mind, the fastest thing you can do is make an array in the first place, and the second fastest is to leave it as a `Vec`.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
// we take mut of vec so you can reuse the vector, if you are consorned about performance
// this should be the default
fn vec_to_array<T, const SIZE: usize>(vec: &mut Vec<T>) -> Option<[T; SIZE]> {
    if vec.len() != SIZE {
        // goes without saying
        return None;
    }

    Some(unsafe { vec_to_array_unchecked(vec) })
}

// # Safety
// Caller must ensure vec.len() == SIZE
unsafe fn vec_to_array_unchecked<T, const SIZE: usize>(vec: &mut Vec<T>) -> [T; SIZE] {
    debug_assert_eq!(vec.len(), SIZE); // debug assert for benefit of future self

    // this just allocates stack or even uninitialized register for small arrays
    // you may want to make this a mut parameter for grater control over stack
    let mut arr: MaybeUninit<[T; SIZE]> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

    let (ptr, len) = (vec.as_ptr(), vec.len());

    // we transfered ownership to array
    vec.set_len(0);

    // move the memory
    std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(ptr, arr.as_mut_ptr() as *mut T, len);

    // array is now initialized
    arr.assume_init()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_vec_to_array() {
        let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // <- only allocation

        let fail = vec_to_array::<i32, 6>(&mut vec);
        assert!(fail.is_none());
        assert_eq!(vec.len(), 5);

        let arr = vec_to_array::<i32, 5>(&mut vec).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(arr, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
        assert_eq!(vec.len(), 0);
    }
}
```