# Pass an array of strings into a function without having to specify N (compile time constant)

Tags: arrays, rust

The following code runs:

```
fn last_el(arr: [&str; 2]) -> usize {
    arr.len() - 1
}

fn main() {
    let names = ["this", "that"];
    println!("{}", names[last_el(names)]);
}
```

However it only does so with `[&str; 2]` and 2 has to match the number of elements in `names`. For example, the following code fails to compile:

```
fn last_el(arr: [&str]) -> usize {
    arr.len() - 1
}

fn main(){
    let names = ["this","that"];
    println!("{}", names[last_el(names)]); 
}
```

How would I write this so that I don't have to specify `N`?

I understand that `arr.len() - 1` is probably less of a headache than trying to write a function that does the same thing, but as far as understanding how functions accept arrays with strings in them, why does the second example fail to compile?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[&str]` is an unsized type. You can't manipulate values of unsized types directly, they need to be behind a reference or a pointer. In your case, you should use `&[&str]` (also called a *slice*).

```
fn last_el(arr: &[&str]) -> usize {
    arr.len() - 1
}

fn main() {
    let names = ["this", "that"];
    println!("{}", names[last_el(&names)]);
}
```

I'll also note that there's a [`last()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.last) method defined on slices. It would be used like this:

```
fn main() {
    let names = ["this", "that"];
    println!("{}", names.last().unwrap()); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And to answer the question you *asked*:

> Pass an **array** of strings into a function without having to specify N

You cannot:

- [How to define a function with a generic fixed-length array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38941025/155423)
- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)