# Implementing a generic length delimited hex deserializer in Serde

Tags: rust, hex, deserialization, serde

I want to use [Serde](https://serde.rs) to take as much responsibility for well-formatted user submitted input as possible. I have a number of fields that require hex values of specific, different length in the input.

How can I use Serde to enforce the allowed character set and the individual field's length without repetitive code?

Up to now, I tried a couple of different approaches. All of them involve the implementation of [custom deserializers](https://serde.rs/impl-deserializer.html). Please let me know if there is a simpler solution, to begin with.

### A macro

A macro `HexString!($name:ident, $length:expr)` that produces two structs: `Name` holding the resulting string and `NameVisitor` implementing the Serde deserialization visitor.

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[macro_use]
extern crate error_chain;

error_chain!{}

macro_rules! HexString {
    ($name:ident, $length:expr) => {
        #[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
        pub struct $name(String);

        impl<'de> serde::de::Deserialize<'de> for $name {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> std::result::Result<Self, D::Error>
            where
                D: serde::de::Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                deserializer.deserialize_str($nameVisitor)
            }
        }

        struct $nameVisitor;

        impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for $nameVisitor {
            type Value = $name;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(
                    formatter,
                    "an string of exactly {} hexadecimal characters",
                    $length
                )
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, s: &str) -> std::result::Result<Self::Value, E>
            where
                E: serde::de::Error,
            {
                use serde::de;
                if s.len() != $length {
                    return Err(de::Error::invalid_value(
                        de::Unexpected::Other(&format!(
                            "String is not {} characters long",
                            $length
                        )),
                        &self,
                    ));
                }
                for c in s.chars() {
                    if !c.is_ascii_hexdigit() {
                        return Err(de::Error::invalid_value(de::Unexpected::Char(c), &self));
                    }
                }

                let mut s = s.to_owned();
                s.make_ascii_uppercase();
                Ok($name(s))
            }
        }
    };
}

HexString!(Sha256, 32);

fn main() {
    let h: Sha256 = serde_json::from_str("a412").unwrap(); // should fail
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=eab5a1e8cfb8463fabbc3444a61463b6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This failed because I was unable to concatenate `$name` and `Visitor` in the pattern.

#### A trait

A trait `HexString` together with a `HexStringVisitor` trait, potentially 
combined with a macro in the end to ease usage:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[macro_use]
extern crate error_chain;

error_chain!{}

trait HexString {
    type T: HexString;
    fn init(s: String) -> Self::T;
    fn len() -> usize;
    fn visitor() -> HexStringVisitor<T=Self::T>;
}

impl<'de, T: HexString> serde::de::Deserialize<'de> for T {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> std::result::Result<Self, D::Error>
    where D: serde::de::Deserializer<'de>
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_str(T::visitor())
    }
}

trait HexStringVisitor {
    type T: HexString;
}

impl<'de, T: HexStringVisitor> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for T {
    type Value = T::T;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "an string of exactly {} hexadecimal characters", Self::Value::len())
    }

    fn visit_str<E>(self, s: &str) -> std::result::Result<Self::Value, E>
        where E: serde::de::Error
    {
        use serde::de;
        if s.len() != Self::Value::len() {
        return Err(de::Error::invalid_value(de::Unexpected::Other(&format!("String is not {} characters long", Self::Value::len())),
        &self));
    }
        for c in s.chars() {
            if !c.is_ascii_hexdigit() {
                return Err(de::Error::invalid_value(de::Unexpected::Char(c), &self));
            }
        }

        let mut s = s.to_owned();
        s.make_ascii_uppercase();
        Ok(T::init(s))
    }
}

struct Sha256(String);
struct Sha256Visitor;

impl HexString for Sha256 {
    type T=Sha256;
    fn init(s: String) -> Sha256 {
        Sha256(s)
    }
    fn len() -> usize {
        32
    }
    fn visitor() -> Sha256Visitor {
        Sha256Visitor()
    }
}

impl HexStringVisitor for Sha256Visitor {
}

fn main() {
    let h: Sha256 = serde_json::from_str("a412").unwrap(); // should fail
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=31f6c78a3bebb7b1cb333861dd82515c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This fails because  I'm not allowed to implement the `Deserialize` trait for any Implementer of `HexString`

Comment: Can you describe how you used the custom deserializer and what are the approaches you tried?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question.

Comment: It would be easy with [this feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580)... But I've no idea for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Boiethios mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649398/rust-serde-implementing-a-generic-length-delimited-hex-deserializer#comment90264537_51649398), this would be more obvious with [const generics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580).

Since that doesn't exist yet, there's two main alternatives. One is to [simulate such a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136739/is-it-possible-to-control-the-size-of-an-array-using-the-type-parameter-of-a-gen), the other is to use an array. In this case, it makes sense to use an array because your data is a fixed length of bytes anyway.

I'd then implement `Deserialize` for a newtype containing any type that can be generated and then accessed as a collection of bytes:

```
extern crate hex;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::de::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Hex<B>(B);

impl<'de, B> serde::de::Deserialize<'de> for Hex<B>
where
    B: AsMut<[u8]> + Default,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> std::result::Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::de::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        let mut b = Hex(B::default());
        match hex::decode(s) {
            Ok(v) => {
                let expected_len = b.0.as_mut().len();
                if v.len() != expected_len {
                    Err(D::Error::custom(format_args!(
                        "Expected input of {} bytes, found {}",
                        expected_len,
                        v.len()
                    )))
                } else {
                    b.0.as_mut().copy_from_slice(&v);
                    Ok(b)
                }
            }
            Err(e) => Err(D::Error::custom(format_args!(
                "Unable to deserialize: {}",
                e
            ))),
        }
    }
}

type Sha16 = Hex<[u8; 2]>;
type Sha256 = Hex<[u8; 32]>;

const TWO_BYTES: &str = r#""a412""#;
const THIRTY_TWO_BYTES: &str =
    r#""2CF24DBA5FB0A30E26E83B2AC5B9E29E1B161E5C1FA7425E73043362938B9824""#;

fn main() {
    let h: Result<Sha256, _> = serde_json::from_str(TWO_BYTES);
    println!("{:?}", h);
    let h: Result<Sha16, _> = serde_json::from_str(TWO_BYTES);
    println!("{:?}", h);

    let h: Result<Sha256, _> = serde_json::from_str(THIRTY_TWO_BYTES);
    println!("{:?}", h);
    let h: Result<Sha16, _> = serde_json::from_str(THIRTY_TWO_BYTES);
    println!("{:?}", h);
}
```

This has two sources of potential inefficiency:

1. We allocate an empty array and then overwrite the bytes
2. We allocate a `Vec` and then copy the bytes from it

There are ways around these, but for the purposes of user input, this is probably reasonable enough.

See also:

- [How to define a function with a generic fixed-length array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38941025/155423)
- [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423)