# Rust how to make function accept list of size n?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn function_name(the_list: ?) {
    // do something
    println!("{}",the_list);
}

fn main() {
    let data = [5,20,18,30,9,7,12,40]; // where data size is n
    let result = function_name(&data);
}
```

I have a very simple function here which I want to pass a list of size n into. I have looked through the docs and only found solutions for lists whose size is known which is not what I want.

How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```rust
fn function_name(the_list: &[i32]) {
    // do something
    println!("{:?}",the_list);
}

fn main() {
    let data = [5,20,18,30,9,7,12,40]; // where data size is n
    let result = function_name(&data);
}

//output: [5, 20, 18, 30, 9, 7, 12, 40]
```

The solution is to have the function accept a general [i32] list type instead. It is not necessary to write the length of the list's input if the input is of size n.

Answer (score 4):

To get compile time information about the size of passed array you can use [const generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136739/is-it-possible-to-control-the-size-of-an-array-using-the-type-parameter-of-a-gen), like this:

```rust
fn function_name<T:Debug, const N: usize>(the_list: &[T; N]) {
    // do something
    println!("{:?}", the_list);
}

fn main() {
    let data = [5,20,18,30,9,7,12,40]; // where data size is n
    let result = function_name(&data);
}
```

If you want to restrict this size to particular value, you can do this:

```rust
fn function_name<T:Debug>(the_list: &[T; 8]) {
```

P.S., `[i32]` is called [primitive array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html).